# How to call Ajax after OnChange or OnSelect event in jQuery DateRangePicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to **select date from calendar after selecting date it will call Ajax with selected date value**  but I am clueless how can I do this, in **Ajax request** I am trying to **put selected date** in place of **pubdate** so that it will request with new date value.

Code

```
    $('#datepick').daterangepicker({ 
    opens: 'center',
    singleDatePicker: true
  },
  function(start) {
   console.log( start.format('DD-MM-YYYY') );
  }
  );
    $.ajax({
 url: "https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/articlelist.php",
  //need to use datepicker date in pubdate
      data:{ Pubid: 2, pubdate: "2021-02-16"},
        type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
      var availableTags=[];
          for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++){
            availableTags[i] = {id: data[i].ArticleID, label: data[i].Title};
          }
   $("#head").autocomplete({
      minLength: 1,
      source: availableTags,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
       $("#head").val(ui.item.label)
        console.log(ui.item.id);
        return false;
         }
       });
},
    error: function (result) {
          alert("Error Heading");
        }

  });
```

In above code I am trying to put **new selected date in place of pubdate and then call my Ajax request**

Answer (score 1):

Put your AJAX call into that first function so that the daterangepicker will run AJAX call after select.

Assuming your start variable is outside of this, you can just pass it into the post data

```
  $('#datepick').daterangepicker({ 
    opens: 'center',
    singleDatePicker: true
  },
  function(start) {
   console.log( start.format('DD-MM-YYYY') );

   $.ajax({
    url: "https://myimpact.in/deletearticle/services/articlelist.php",
     //need to use datepicker date in pubdate
         data:{ Pubid: 2, pubdate: start},
           type: "POST",
       dataType: "JSON",
           success: function(data){
         var availableTags=[];
             for(var i=0;i<data.length; i++){
               availableTags[i] = {id: data[i].ArticleID, label: data[i].Title};
             }
      $("#head").autocomplete({
         minLength: 1,
         source: availableTags,
         select: function( event, ui ) {
          $("#head").val(ui.item.label)
           console.log(ui.item.id);
           return false;
            }
          });
   },
       error: function (result) {
             alert("Error Heading");
           }
   
     });


  }
  );
```

Comment: Getting Error `moment.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_calendar' of undefined
    at zc (moment.min.js:6)
    at add (jquery-1.12.4.js:10073)
    at buildParams (jquery-1.12.4.js:10061)
    at buildParams (jquery-1.12.4.js:10055)
    at buildParams (jquery-1.12.4.js:10055)
    at Function.jQuery.param (jquery-1.12.4.js:10095)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-1.12.4.js:9612)
    at DateRangePicker.callback (index.php:119)
    at DateRangePicker.hide (daterangepicker.js:1140)
    at DateRangePicker.clickApply`